# Can I use grunt to set a property value in a json file?

Tags: javascript, json, gruntjs

Still learning the ropes of grunt and can't find a solution for this. 
I have a config file, say config.json with some data.

When I run a specific grunt task I want to increment a value in the config.json file. I've been able to find a lot of information on how to read the file but nothing so far on changing a value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use https://github.com/eruizdechavez/grunt-string-replace for replace string and save file

```
'string-replace': {
  dist: {
    files: {
      'dest/': 'src/**',
      'prod/': ['src/*.js', 'src/*.css'],
    },
    options: {
      replacements: [{
        pattern: /\/(asdf|qwer)\//ig,
        replacement: '"$1"'
      }, {
        pattern: ',',
        replacement: ';'
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

with this grunt plugin u can substitute a regex pattern (or a simple string) with a replacement

the steps for make your final json are:

- load the json file >> http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file
- apply the replace task >> on the top
- save json file >> *grunt.file.write(filepath, contents [, options])*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a way to just write a property value to the json, in the same way as grunt can read the values, but it seems like this is the only way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution based off of [giammangiato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6691733/giammangiato)'s answer.

I read the JSON file, made my changes and then just replaced the whole file by writing a new one using the modified JSON like so:

```
var mrJSON = grunt.file.readJSON('myDir/config.json');

    var mrNumber  = mrJSON.number;

    mrNumber++;


    grunt.file.write('myDir/config.json', JSON.stringify(mrJSON));
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of updating the version of the package.json file using a grunt task. (from 0.0.0 to 1.0.0 to 2.0.0);

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('version', function(key, value) {
        var projectFile = "package.json";
        if (!grunt.file.exists(projectFile)) {
            grunt.log.error("file " + projectFile + " not found");
            return true; //return false to abort the execution
        }
        var project = grunt.file.readJSON(projectFile), //get file as json object
            currentVersion = project["version"].split('.');

        currentVersion[lastIndex] = Number(currentVersion[0]) + 1
        currentVersion = currentVersion.join('.');

        project["version"] = currentVersion;
        grunt.file.write(projectFile, JSON.stringify(project, null, 2));
    });
}
```

now you can call the task version to increment the file by writing

```
grunt version
```

or you can add it to your production process, for example:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('buildProd', [
      'version'
    ]);
};
```

Comment: for this task a cute grunt tool is https://github.com/vojtajina/grunt-bump